# Adding Textures/Patterns to Text [Krita 4.15]

Tags: text, texture, krita

I wanted to **add textures/pattern overlays to my Thumbnail text** on vector layers(similar to paint brushes on rasterlayers ) in Krita 4.15.

There is an option provided under the Text_ToolOptions menu to add patterns but on activating it ,no changes can be seen in the text.

Under the patterns panel (under toolbar), a pattern can be selected but the selected pattern doesnot show up in the text .

Just to clear things up ,is there the option to add add textures/pattern overlays to my Thumbnail text on vector layers?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Textures can be added to Text in Krita by applying them via **a Separate layer and then  blending them with  the "Overlay" mode.**

1.Add Text as a Vector layer and then convert it to a Paint layer (as Krita doesn't recognise filters on Vector layers).
2.**Add a Paint layer above the text layer** and fill it with the necessary texture by going to Edit>Fill with Pattern
3.The texture layer will have a **default "Normal" blend mode , change it to "Overlay".**

The Texture will be applied to the Text.
[image]